# Create recyclerview in onOptionsItemSelected and not onCreate in activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview that is not found in onCreate, but in onOptionsItemSelected. Here's why: When I click on an item in the options menu, I display a bottom sheet, see: ([google specs](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html) and the [library](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet)). The library takes a xml-layout, which is where my recyclerview is located. The problem is that when I'm attaching the layout manager to the recyclerview I get this exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.canScrollVertically()'
>   on a null object reference
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange(RecyclerView.java:1545)
>               at android.view.View.onDrawScrollBars(View.java:12943)
>               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15237)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:3037)
>               at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14167)
>               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
>               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
>               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
>               at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14167)
>               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
>               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
>               at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14162)
>               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
>               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
>               at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1089)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
>               at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14162)
>               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
>               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
>               at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14162)
>               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
>               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
>               at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14162)
>               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
>               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
>               at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14162)
>               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
>               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
>               at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14162)
>               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
>               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14959)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
>               at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:598)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2650)
>               at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14167)
>               at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
>               at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:273)
>               at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:279)
>               at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:318)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2530)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2352)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1982)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreo

So my question is: How to I create a recyclerview in anything else besides onCreate of activity, or onCreateView of fragment?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Below is my process of creating the recyclerview: First I instantiate the bottom sheet. See code below

```
private BottomSheetLayout bottomSheet;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

        bottomSheet = (BottomSheetLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottomsheet);
}
```

In onOptionsItemSelected I create the recyclerview. see code below

```
List<BottomSheetData> mCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();

BottomSheetAdapter bottomAdapter = new BottomSheetAdapter(mCategoryList); //Recyclerview adapter

RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this)); //error caused here 
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(bottomAdapter);
```

Here is my bottom sheet layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FAF9F7">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//error caused here
```

Not directly. If it were, you would see it in the stack trace.

Now, your line numbers do not match the `master` branch of [the `RecyclerView` source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.java), so start by making sure that you are on the latest `recyclerview-v7` (22.2.1), in case you are tripping over a `RecyclerView` bug.

In fact, there [is (or was) a bug with `RecyclerView`](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=163026) that mimics your stack trace, tied to your having the `android:scrollbars` attribute. That bug was with the IDE rendering code; [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180646) is with `RecyclerView` itself. So, if the problem persists when you move to 22.2.1, try removing `android:scrollbars`, and see if that helps. Note that if it is not fixed in 22.2.1, I doubt that it will ever be fixed, as Google has declined that second bug report.

Comment: My problem was, that I wasn't accessing the view where the recyclerview was located. This is why I got the null-pointer exception. :) Thanks for the help.